# Is it possible to use fold in Rust if the accumulator is neither copy type nor mutable

Tags: rust, fold

I am trying to make a fold work and encountered with lifetime issues. Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
struct A {
  v: i32,
}
let v = vec![A { v: 1 }, A { v: 2 }, A { v: 3 }];
let max = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<A>, &item| { match res {
    Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(item) },
    None => Some(item)
}});
```

This results in `error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content`.

If I change the closure to `|res: Option<A>, ref item| ...` as adviced by the previous error, I get a type mismatch at `Some(item)` and solving that dereference gets back to the original error.

I tried to have a reference in the option but then I get lifetime issues:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> <anon>:6:67
  |
6 |   let maxV = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<&A>, &item| { match res {
  |                                                                   ^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 6:58...
 --> <anon>:6:59
  |
6 |     let maxV = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<&A>, &item| { match res {
  |  ___________________________________________________________^ starting here...
7 | |       Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(&item) },
8 | |       None => Some(&item)
9 | |   }});
  | |____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected std::option::Option<&main::A>, found std::option::Option<&main::A>)
 --> <anon>:6:67
  |
6 |   let maxV = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<&A>, &item| { match res {
  |                                                                   ^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the method call at 6:13...
 --> <anon>:6:14
  |
6 |     let maxV = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<&A>, &item| { match res {
  |  ______________^ starting here...
7 | |       Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(&item) },
8 | |       None => Some(&item)
9 | |   }});
  | |_____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
 --> <anon>:6:28
  |
6 |   let maxV = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<&A>, &item| { match res {
  |                            ^^^^
```

The first version works if I make A a copy type by adding `#[derive (Copy, Clone)]` but that is not always an option.

I tried to search for fold examples in rust, but I either found ones where the accumulator is a copy type (i32 sums implemented with fold) or where the accumulator is a container and the fold is manipulating the content (extending a vector or similar).

I also found [an example that folds into an Option](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e1cb9ba221e5cb0070ac82c6a234af11e4240680/src/libsyntax/attr.rs#L421) but that does not match on the current value of the accumulator.

I can do it with a for loop but would prefer the fold syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several bugs in the compiler regarding the inference of lifetime parameters on closure parameters; the one you've encountered here has been reported as [issue 36867](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36867). In `res: Option<&A>`, the lifetime inferred for `&A` is wrong, and it seems to be caused by the return type (which is `Option<&A>`) also having a lifetime parameter. The workaround is to let the compiler infer **the whole type**, which works fine, and instead either give a type hint on the initial accumulator value (`None`):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    v: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![A { v: 1 }, A { v: 2 }, A { v: 3 }];
    let max = v.iter().fold(None::<&A>, |res, item| { match res {
        Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(item) },
        None => Some(item)
    }});
    println!("{:?}", max);
}
```

or on the `max` variable:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![A { v: 1 }, A { v: 2 }, A { v: 3 }];
    let max: Option<&A> = v.iter().fold(None, |res, item| { match res {
        Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(item) },
        None => Some(item)
    }});
    println!("{:?}", max);
}
```

**Bonus:** For the particular problem of finding the maximum, you can also use [`Iterator::max_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by_key). No annotations required!

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![A { v: 1 }, A { v: 2 }, A { v: 3 }];
    let max = v.iter().max_by_key(|item| item.v);
    println!("{:?}", max);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the bug?

Comment: Edited the question with the closest match I could find. There are so many bugs reported against closures and some contradict each other! e.g. in [issue 24680](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24680), you *need* to specify the argument's type to avoid a compiler error, which is the opposite from the problem here!

Comment: Thanks, I had a map after the fold in the original code that is why I could not specify the type on max and failed to do it on None. Now it works perfectly,
`max_by_key` is actually what I needed, was focusing on the fold too much.

Comment: As I commented on the other answer also, I just realised that if I have the `None => Some(item)` match first then it helps the compiler to infer the type of the accumulator correctly and I do not need type hints.

Answer (score 3):

The iterator you get from `Vec::iter()` produces immutable borrowed references (`&A` in this case) to the elements in the vector; the vector will be unchanged afterwards.

As a reminder, by default in Rust using a value [moves it out](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html#move-semantics), leaving the orignal unusable; you can only do this if you own the item, i.e. you can't move out of a borrowed reference.  The exception to this is with types which are `Copy`, which means that they're "simple enough" that a raw memory copy is ok and doesn't invalidate the original object.

So for any type which is not `Copy`, you can't assign directly from an immutable reference.

There are several options.

First, if you can implement or derive `Clone` (which means you provide a method which can copy the object, possibly doing more than just a raw copy) without `Copy`, you can do explicitly clone:

```
let max = v.iter().fold(None, |res: Option<A>, item| match res {
    Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(item.clone()) },
    None => Some(item.clone()),
});
```

You could manually construct the new items inline (`Some(A { v: item.v })`), but if you're doing that you may as well derive or implement `Clone`.

If you can consume (i.e. destroy) your vector of items to get the result, then you can move after all by calling the `into_iter()` method instead of `iter()`; the iterator in that case owns the items (the original owner, the `Vec`, is consumed in the process) so you can move them:

```
let max = v.into_iter().fold(None, |res: Option<A>, item| match res {
    Some(a) => if a.v >= item.v { Some(a) } else { Some(item) },
    None => Some(item),
});
```

Moving works fine there, but the `Vec` no longer exists.

Either way, you either need to make a copy (via `Copy`, `Clone`, or something more manual) or move - it's up to your application which is more appropriate.

Comment: could you explain further why the original code was giving error? There's always a solution using clone/copy or using into_iter(), but can it be solved using references only

Comment: I wanted to get another immutable borrow on the item. I started with `Option<&A>` but did not understand the lifetime problem. The whole thing started by that the compiler could not interfere the type of `a` in `Some(a)` and I just realised that if I have the `None` matching line first than the whole thing works without type annotation as `None => Some(item)` will help the compiler to infer the return type of match to `Option<&A>` with correct lifetimes.